# Using AND operator with Multiple Criteria for Conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to highlight cells between two percentage values, however I only want to highlight them if an adjacent cell contains the text value "RRB"

I was successful in creating a formula to highlight cells when I only had TWO conditions:

```
 =AND($D2="RRB",$E2>=1)
```

HIGHLIGHTS GREEN CELLS IN COLUMN E ">=" 100%, IF CELL IN COLUMN D = "RRB"

```
 =AND($D2="RRB",$E2<0.75)
```

HIGHLIGHTS RED CELLS IN COLUMN E "<" 75%, IF CELL IN COLUMN D = "RRB"

However, when I added the third condition to highlight yellow values between 74% and 100% the conditional formatting did not work. What am I doing wrong with my formula?

I tried both of these below and neither worked, I am at a loss. I was thinking about using IF but that didn't seem right either.

```
=AND($D2="RRB",$E2>=0.75,$E2<1)

=AND($D2="RRB",AND($E2>=0.75,$E2<1))
```

Comment: Just use `=$D2="RRB"`

Comment: Thank you, however that will highlight ALL %'s in column E, where the adjacent cell in column D  = "RRB". I ONLY want those %'s between 74% and 100% to highlight in column E.

Comment: If you make it the third in priority it will only do the ones that have `RRB` and do not fall in the other two.

Comment: Thank you! Can you show me what this formula would look like? Would it be: =AND($E2>=0.75,$E2<1,$D2="RRB")

Comment: I tried that and it WORKED - Thank you so much!